# Git: Squash feature branch and merge commit, rebase on master

Tags: git

I have the following scenario:

```
M
|
|
o  X
| /| 
|/ |
a  b
| /
|/
o
```

I checked out `b`, then ran `git merge a`. There were some conflicts which were resolved in the merge commit `X`. I also did some misc changes within `X`.

I want to squash `X` and `b`, and then rebase the squash on `M`.
The goal is to avoid re-doing the changes that were done to build `X`.

```
(X+b)
  |
  |
  M
  |
  |
  o
  |
  |
  a
  |
  |
  o
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried interactive rebase? First checkout X, then `git rebase -i M`, and then pick `squash` on line 2 and onwards?

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I did, but I think I needed to resolve the original merge conflicts again. I will double check.

Comment: It might be, and I'm not sure that's really avoidable. Rebasing is quite different from merging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can :

```
# from X :
git reset --soft o    # <- the parent commit of a and b
git commit            # this will create 'b + X'

# then rebase :
git rebase M
```

You may have extra conflicts to fix when rebasing.

---

An alternative way can be :

- first merge `M` and `X`
- then use `reset --soft + commit` to create a single commit

```
# from commi M :
git merge X
# fix possible merge conflicts

git reset --soft M
git commit    # commit the content of the merge
              # as a single regular commit on top of M
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method:

```
git checkout M
git merge --squash X
git commit -m "implemented feature X"
```